# PassportJS: BasicStrategy vs LocalStrategy?

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js

While looking at the many PassportJS examples, I was quite confused about the use of BasicStrategy.

Some people use it for username/password authentication, others for clientID/clientSecret authentication, while some people don't use LocalStrategy at all.

What would be the correct purpose of BasicStrategy? Shouldn't only ClientPasswordStrategy be used to authenticate clients via ID/secret?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187345/what-are-the-differences-between-local-basic-and-digest-strategy-in-passportjs

Comment: @hassansin sorry, but it doesn't answer my question, as it didn't describe the user/client difference at all

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between BasicStrategy and LocalStrategy is the way the id and secret are send.

When using Basicstrategy the id and secret are send using basic http authentication.

When using the LocalStrategy the id and secret are send using the request body or url parameters.